# list function is not working after python upgrade to 3.6.3

Tags: python-3.x

I recently upgraded my python version from 2.6 to 3.6.3. the below code is throwing exception while using list function. I found out that code is failing only for the files having records more than 255. Not sure how to fix this, appreciate your help.

```
try:            
            with open(filePath) as f:                
                fileReader = csv.reader(f, delimiter='\t', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)                

                fileAsList = list(fileReader)
                return fileAsList
        except:
            print ("Oops!! Can't get that file.")
```

Comment: What exception? Did you accidentally redefine `list` somewhere?

Comment: And I tried formatting your code, but your indentation is all off. Please fix it.

Comment: Your `except:` block may be obscuring the problem. Remove it and see what exception you actually get.

Comment: I have not defined 'list' anywhere. Also have print the exception, here it is:: 
e={UnicodeDecodeError} 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8f in position 4633: character maps to <undefined>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it resolved by adding encoding while opening the file. Below code worked:

```
    try:            
        with open(filePath, 'r', encoding='latin1') as f:                
            fileReader = csv.reader(f, delimiter='\t', 
                                   quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)                

            fileAsList = list(fileReader)
            return fileAsList
    except:
        print ("Oops!! Can't get that file.")
```